# Error in google spreadsheet with arrays

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

In google spreadsheet I receive an error and it says, "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in M261". I looked in M261 and it is a blank cell, but the weird thing is if I hit the delete button on the empty cell, then the error goes away. Sadly it keeps coming back. Is there a fix for this?

Here is my formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E>0,IF(D2:D=0,"Need Due Date",""),""))

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour, but try using empty arguments rather than `""` which produces a zero-length text string, ie: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E>0,IF(D2:D=0,"Need Due Date",),))`

Answer (score 0):

I did not see "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in M261" but at one point did see "...Add more rows".

One approach that should I think work is to restrict the output range of your formula. So for example if you wish it to apply to 100 rows, use:

```
=array_constrain(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E>0,IF(D2:D=0,"Need Due Date",""),"")),100,1)
```

However the problem you mention and the error message I saw are both because it is an array formula. There seems little need for it to be such and something like:

```
=if(and(D2=0,E2>0),"Need Due Date",)
```

is much faster, specially for a large number of rows, though unlike the array version does require copying down.